# Play a YouTube Video in Your android app

Tags: java, android

hello there i have created an app for playing Youtube videos i works fine but i want when i click on next button the next videos plays. how i will create an array for it which contain the youtube videos link. i m new to Android programming plz help.

```
public class TutorialsActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

public static final String DEVELOPER_KEY = "AIzaSyAIeerJ_5ClQHLtIpXtk5DH2S4mZ9lwGKs";
private static final String VIDEO_ID = "eQW4R5gLlUk";
private static final String VIDEO_ID1 = "H2c_x4YWx7I";
private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;
YouTubePlayerFragment myYouTubePlayerFragment;
Button btnNext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tutorials);

    myYouTubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtubeplayerfragment);
    myYouTubePlayerFragment.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);

}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, final YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
    if (!wasRestored) {
        player.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);
    }
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            player.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID1);
        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST) {
     // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
        getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    }
}
protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
    return (YouTubePlayerView)findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayerfragment);
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

just i shared my working source of your requirement.

**SampleActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import www.ns7.tv.R;
import www.ns7.tv.controller.YoutubeManager;

public class SampleActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener, View.OnClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = "YoutubeLiveTvActivity";
    private Button mBtnNext;
    private YouTubePlayerView mYouTubePlayerView = null;
    private YouTubePlayer mLiveTvPlayer = null;
    private ArrayList<String> mVideoIdList = new ArrayList<>();
    private int mOffset = 0;
    private String mCurrentVideoId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.sample);
        mBtnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        mYouTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
        mYouTubePlayerView.initialize(YoutubeManager.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);

        mBtnNext.setOnClickListener(this);
        updateVideoIdList();//add all video id in list
        updateVideoId();//set current video id to mCurrentVideoId string
    }

    private void updateVideoId() {
        if (mOffset >= mVideoIdList.size())
            mOffset = 0;
        mCurrentVideoId = mVideoIdList.get(mOffset);
    }

    private void updateVideoIdList() {
        mVideoIdList.clear();
        mVideoIdList.add("p0JcLbXfYXA");
        mVideoIdList.add("63pKwVE4Uog");
        mVideoIdList.add("QJXsurYoJ10");
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
        try {
            youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.MINIMAL);
            mLiveTvPlayer = youTubePlayer;
            //  mLiveTvPlayer.setOnFullscreenListener(YoutubeLiveTvActivity.this);
            if (!b) {
                mYouTubePlayerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                youTubePlayer.loadVideo(mCurrentVideoId);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, " error : ", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mLiveTvPlayer == null) {
            mYouTubePlayerView.initialize(YoutubeManager.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);
        } else {
            mLiveTvPlayer.loadVideo(mCurrentVideoId);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        if (mLiveTvPlayer != null) {
            mLiveTvPlayer.release();
        }
        if (mYouTubePlayerView != null) {
            mYouTubePlayerView.removeAllViews();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId())
        {
            case R.id.btnNext:
            {
                mOffset++;// move the mOffset to next video id
                updateVideoId();
                mLiveTvPlayer.loadVideo(mCurrentVideoId);//load next video
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**sample.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnNext"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        >

        <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
            android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"

            />

    </RelativeLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Next"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

*Above code youtube video play at 0 position when you click next button , next video will be play. if list last item reached then it will again move to 0 position.*

**Output :**

[image]